# How to remove smoothing on trimesh viewer SceneWidget

Tags: python, mesh, pyglet

I have a detailed mesh (`my_mesh`) created with trimesh (python package). I can visualize it with `my_mesh.show(smooth=False)`, and the option to remove smoothness and obtain a detailed view is clear.

Now I want to do view the mesh in a glooey and pyglet gui, and therefore use `trimesh.viewer.SceneWidget()`. Here I cannot find the way to remove the smoothness from the resulting visualization of my_mesh.

relevant code snippet:

```
scene = trimesh.Scene()
scene.add_geometry(my_mesh)
self.scene_widget1 = trimesh.viewer.SceneWidget(scene)
hbox.add(self.scene_widget1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trimesh package had to be modified. I have contributed to the open source project and it will be included in the next release.